# File Uploading in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to make a file uploading page in my MVC project. First of all i want to manage this locally.
My Questions are:
1- Here is my controller and view. Is there any thing that I have to do to make this code work? I mean defining a model or using jquery, etc. What is the process when a file is being uploaded?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("C:/Users/marti/../PhotoGallery/myimages"),
                 Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
                uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
            return View();
}
```

Here is the View:

```
<input name="uploadFile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

2- When i debug this, It never goes to controller.

Comment: Not sure of the question. What doesn't work? Or do you just want a file upload progress?

Comment: You need to use Html form `<form>` tag to submit it via a post request and accept `FormCollection collection` in your controller.

Comment: Yes i needed file uploading progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` on your view form:

```
    @model ImageModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "New Image";
    }
    <div class="content-form-container width-half">
        <form id='PropertiesForm' action='@Url.Action(ImageController.Actions.Add, ImageController.Name)' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' class='content-form'>
        @Html.Partial("ImageName")
        <fieldset class='content-form-1field'>
            <div class='legend'>
                file to upload
            </div>
            @Html.LabelledFileInput(ImageView.FileName, string.Empty)
        </fieldset>
        <div class='buttons'>
            @Html.Button("button-submit", "submit")
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    @section script{
        @Html.JavascriptInclude("~/js/image/new.min.js")
    }
```

And here is my controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [MemberAccess]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var name = ImageView.ImageName.MapFrom(Request.Form);

        if (Request.Files.Count == 0)
        {
            RegisterFailureMessage("No file has been selected for upload.");

            return ValidationFailureAdd(name);
        }

        var file = Request.Files[0];

        if (file == null || file.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            RegisterFailureMessage("No file has been selected for upload or the file is empty.");

            return ValidationFailureAdd(name);
        }

        var format = ImageService.ImageFormat(file.InputStream);

        if (format != ImageFormat.Gif && format != ImageFormat.Jpeg && format != ImageFormat.Png)
        {
            RegisterFailureMessage("Only gif, jpg and png files are supported.");

            return ValidationFailureAdd(name);
        }

        if (query.HasName(name))
        {
            RegisterFailureMessage(string.Format("Image with name '{0}' already exists.", name));

            return ValidationFailureAdd(name);
        }

        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();

            var fileExtension = ImageService.FileExtension(format);

            Bus.Send(new AddWikiImageCommand
                     {
                         Id = id,
                         Name = name,
                         FileExtension = fileExtension
                     });

            var path = Path.Combine(ApplicationConfiguration.MediaFolder,
                                    string.Format("{0}.{1}", id.ToString("n"), fileExtension));

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }

            file.SaveAs(path);

            scope.Complete();
        }

        return RedirectToAction(Actions.Manage);
    }
```

There are some custom bits in there so you can ignore those.  The gyst of what you need should be there.

HTH

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) I sude this and it works.

Comment: @Mgnfcnt: yes, you can :) --- Doesn't buy you too much, though.  I *do* have my own Html.ContentForm implementation that adds some stuff for me when I have typicall data entry forms.  But Html.BeginForm is definitely an option.